# Android app crash for cordova expansion file plugin

Tags: android, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, apk-expansion-files

I have implemented expansion file by following this tutorial https://iphonedevlog.wordpress.com/2014/12/12/adding-an-android-apk-expansion-file-to-a-cordova-project. I have used the expansion file cordova plugin https://github.com/agamemnus/cordova-plugin-xapkreader/tree/cordova-6.5.0 .

I published the application as alpha to play store for testing. The application crashed while launching and give notification of downloading as the picture below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We need to modify some config as follow:

1. in ./config.xml

   ```
    <variable name="XAPK_EXPANSION_AUTHORITY" value="PACKAGE_NAME" />
    <variable name="XAPK_PUBLIC_KEY" value="PUBLIC_API_KEY" />
    <variable name="XAPK_PATCH_VERSION" value="-1" />
   ```
2. in ./plugins/android.json

   ```
   "com.flyingsoftgames.xapkreader": {
       "XAPK_EXPANSION_AUTHORITY": "PACKAGE_NAME",
       "XAPK_PUBLIC_KEY": "PUBLIC_API_KEY",
       "XAPK_PATCH_VERSION": "-1"
   }
   ```
3. in ./platforms/android.json

   ```
   "res/values/xapkreader.xml": {
           "parents": {
               "/*": [
                   {
                       "xml": "<string name=\"xapk_expansion_authority\">PACKAGE_NAME</string>",
                       "count": 1
                   },
                   {
                       "xml": "<string name=\"xapk_google_play_public_key\">PUBLIC_API_KEY</string>",
                       "count": 1
                   },
                   {
                       "xml": "<integer name=\"xapk_patch_version\">-1</integer>",
                       "count": 1
                   }
               ]
           }
       }
   ```
4. in ./platforms/res/values/xapkreader.xml

   ```
    <resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <string name="xapk_expansion_authority">PACKAGE_NAME </string>
       <string name="xapk_google_play_public_key">PUBLIC_API_KEY </string>
       <integer name="xapk_patch_version">-1</integer>
    </resources>
   ```

Note: don't forget to replace in PACKAGE_NAME and PUBLIC_API_KEY as your config of application.